# Instantiated prefab loses script reference

Tags: unity-game-engine

My prefab will not retain the move joystick reference. If I add the reference back while running, the everything works, but the instantiated prefab will lost the reference once I delete it from the screen, or run the project.

I was sure to hit Apply on the prefab, but essentially, its acting as though I didn't.

the reference is added here...

[image]

but gone on the instantiated object...

[image]

Note that the ship object that I drag into the scene still has the reference, but the instantiated ship does not.

I've tried this with the joystick container as a prefab and not a prefab.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## This is expected behavior

Prefabs cannot maintain references to objects in the scene, as when they get instantiated, there's no guaranteed that that object still exists.

You will have to assign the reference to the script when you instantiate the prefab. You can do this by calling `instance_obj.GetComponent<Move>().moveJoystick = ...`

Comment: It looks like this is something different since he is trying to access a script, not a gameobject in the scene.

Comment: He is accesing a script inside a gameobject in the scene (JoystickContainer inside of canvas) so its the expected behaviour case.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I missed that part. Lets make it more easy for him if he cant make it right. First add a tag called "JoystickContainer" to your JoystickContainer gameobject. Then in your "Move" script, set the MoveJoystick variable to this; Movejoystick = GameObject.FindWithTag("JoystickContainer"); This will work for sure.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working because the variable is of type joystick, which doesn't match GameObject. Still working through it.

Comment: You need to call `GetComponent<>()` on the GameObject with the type of the joystick script inside the `<>`

Comment: Got it. Thank you.